# Dynamic Url and Title in Asp.net mvc Sitemap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using asp.net mvc sitemap for my blog site and there is one problem arises when I try to give dynamic url and title in Mvc.sitemap xml file. I do not want to use DynamicNodeProvider because in this we need to iterate all blogs and it slows down my application.

My controller and action code is like that:

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(int id, string title)
    {
    }
}
```

Mvc.sitemap xml is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="DevSection" controller="DevSection" action="Index" key="DevSection">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Articles" controller="DevSection" action="Article" key="Articles">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="" controller="Articles" action="Index" url="" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
 </mvcSiteMap>
```

In above Mvc.sitemap xml the bold highlighted mvcSiteMapNode title and url is blank because I am not getting an idea how to pass dynamic build url and display the output like this:

```
Home – DevSection – Articles – <dynamic title>
```

Please help me, how can I achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `http://joelabrahamsson.com/xml-sitemap-with-aspnet-mvc/`

Comment: is it helpful to you?

Comment: please give me another example

Comment: this is not a answer of my question.

Comment: try this: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/06/16/ASPNET-MVC-MvcSiteMapProvider-20-is-out!.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is make a dynamic breadcrumb trail, you can use preservedRouteParameters to make a single node force a match on the route values of every article.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="DevSection" controller="DevSection" action="Index" key="DevSection">
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="Articles" controller="DevSection" action="Article" key="Articles">
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="" controller="Articles" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="id,title" />
            </mvcSiteMapNode>
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

Then you can use the SiteMapTitle attribute to dynamically change the title of the node.

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    [SiteMapTitle("title")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id, string title)
    {
    }
}
```

You may also need to use the [FitleredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider) to hide the node with the "dynamic URL" from the menu.

However, if you intend to use the built-in [sitemaps XML](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Sitemaps-XML-Protocol-Endpoint-for-Search-Engines) functionality so your articles are indexed in search engines, you are better off using DynamicNodeProvider.

For a full discussion of this topic, see [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position).

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. I actually did not have to add the SiteMapTitle attribute and it still worked.